# Using javascript to pause background scroll to allow for fixed elements to have slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so the effect I am trying to emulate can be found on the nexus 5 site - http://www.google.com/nexus/5/ - when you scroll to the phone section. I've viewed source and looked through the code but there is over 13k lines of js so it was a waste.

Anyways what I did was add a class to fix the position of the images and created a background div that was like 5000px so it would appear to be fixed. The js fixed the position after the screen reached a certain point and then removed the fixed class after the end of the div.

My question is that i know this can be done better  than my janky 'hack'. I'd love to hear your thoughts on better implementation.

This is part of the code that adds the fixed class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {    



    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".container").addClass("fixed");

    } 
    if (scroll >= 8000) {
     $(".container").removeClass("fixed");
 }


});
```

Comment: Do you have any code for what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this guide:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/multiplane-design-with-svgs-and-css-3d-transforms

Demo: http://codepen.io/nickpettit/full/eBCrK

Haven't done something like this before myself however. Also just a note that fixed position elements from my experience act up when viewed on tablet/smartphone.

Comment: interesting, but how would you insert that in between normal scrolling divs